# How to map JPA OneToMany relationship when FK is part of CompositeId

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

So I have a pre-existing Service Entity with multiple OneToMany relationships. Now I need to add one more but I am having trouble and I assume it must be because the Many side uses a Composite Key.

I have the Service.java with its new fields

```
@Column(name = "TRANSLATION_DV_ID")
private String translationDvId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.All, fetch = FetchType.Eager, mappedBy = "service")
private List<Translation> translation;
```

and

```
@IdClass(TranslationId.class)
public class Translation {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "TRANSLATION_DV_ID")
 private String translationDvId;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "LOCALE_CD")
 private String localeCd;

 @Column(name = "TRANSLATED_NAME")
 private String translatedName;

 @Column(name = "TRANSLATED_DESC")
 private String translatedDesc;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSLATION_DV_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Service service;
```

The test data is generated with sql scripts. I entered the new data and matched the translationDvId's. The data is all present with the correct information except for Translation relationship- each Service always has an empty `List<Translation>`.

I am not sure what I am missing but here is an example of a data entry

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.SERVICE(SERVICE_CD, TRANSLATION_DV_ID, etc, etc)
VALUES ('servicePrimaryKey', '12345', 'etc, 'etc);

INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TRANSLATION(TRANSLATION_DV_ID, LOCALE_CD, TRANSLATED_NAME, TRANSLATED_DESC)
VALUES ('12345', 'English', 'Guardian', 'Cool stuff');
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TRANSLATION(TRANSLATION_DV_ID, LOCALE_CD, TRANSLATED_NAME, TRANSLATED_DESC)
VALUES ('12345', 'Spanish', 'Guardia', 'Cosas interesantes');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JoinColumn has a special property for when there is a Composite PK in the referenced table - referencedColumnName

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSLATION_DV_ID", referencedColumnName = "TRANSLATION_DV_ID")
private List<Translation> translation;
```